# Core Data Entity Not Saving Between Launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm having a issue with something I'm working one. My application so far consists of two UITableView controllers and a single ViewController. The app simply asks the user to enter the name of a list on UIAlert and it saves to core data, and the name of the list is put into the first tableview. Then the user clicks on the name of the list and it pushes them to the contents on the list, which is empty because it hasn't been populated yet. Then the user populates the TableView, so it pushes to the single view controller where you would enter all the info and hit save and it saves as an item. So my problem is when I go to add an item it saves but then when I restart my app it the list is still there but all the items in the list are gone. I have have no idea why it's doing this do if you have any suggestions let me know! Thanks!

I put the project on GitHub because there is a lot of code, also it allows you to experience my issue, and understand the flow of the controllers. https://github.com/jackintosh7/test-master

My Add Item .m:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];



    [newItem setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"itemName"];
    [newItem setValue:self.price.text forKey:@"price"];
    [newItem setValue:self.desc.text forKey:@"description"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: That's too much code to expect people to go through. You can put the link to GitHub but copy/paste the small bit of code related to saving/retrieving the object in question.

Comment: The first question I would ask is are you certain it is saving your data? When you call `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`, what is contained the error object? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJCEDBI

Comment: Ok I added some code from my add item's .m And yes the data is saving but when I restart the app it doesn't show. I don't have an error or anything just the items I added aren't showing, when I restart it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Very helpful for the future:** As a sanity check I'd first check to see if the items in your list are actually being saved. You can use the simulator and a tool like CoreDataPro to view your store. When I was first learning iOS programming and Core Data this was extremely helpful:
https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility

Using the above utility, I saw your items were in fact **not** saving to your persistent store.

I took a look at your revised code and made a few small edits and all seems to be working.

1) In AddViewController.h : Import item.h and list.h. Most importantly, add a List strong property to your AddViewController so your new Item has a reference to the applicable list.

```
#import "Item.h" //Your forward @class definitions would probably work. 
#import "List.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) List *list;
```

2) Reduced code in WishListView.m prepareForSegue: Simply passing the List and ManagedObjectContext to the destination ViewController.

```
else if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddItem"] ) {
    destViewController.list = self.list;
    destViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    destViewController.completionBlock = ^(BOOL saved){
            _items = nil;
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
    };
}
```

3) Creating the NSEntityDescription inside AddViewController.m instead of passing it. Also saving the List from the new `list` property we created.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
self.item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
self.item.name = self.name.text;
self.item.price = self.price.text;
self.item.desc = self.desc.text;
self.item.list = self.list;

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

if( self.completionBlock ) {
    self.completionBlock(YES);
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: Sure thing. One way to avoid naming problems like this in the future, and let XCode do the work for you, is directly reference the @property of your entities by writing '[item setName]'  or 'item.name ='. You'll get a warning or error if you reference an incorrect property name, and you likely won't even get to that point since the lack of autocomplete by XCode will tell you something is wrong beforehand.

Comment: Ok take a look at this, I accidently uploaded a previous copy of my app, this is the latest version: https://github.com/jackintosh7/test-master

Comment: I took a look and think your code should be fixed. Let me know if you need additional help, or would like me to issue a pull request to your Github repository so you can have the fixed code all in one place. An upvote and accepted answer would be much appreciated :) Cheers!

Comment: Ok I just fixed that and it worked! Thanks a ton! I'll let you know if I have any more questions.

Comment: I have a question for you when you get a chance.

Comment: Sure, shoot. Perhaps make a new question?

Comment: Here's the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951791/click-to-add-image-to-core-data/22953293?noredirect=1#22953293, you have all ready seen my code so you know what I'm working with. I have my updated code on the Github link I provided in the question, feel free to make any changes. Thanks!